# To get value from user control using ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have datalist in field.ascx and i have a label and textbox in fields.ascx and i am binding textbox and label dynamically in datalist and display in webform.aspx.Now i want to get label text and textbox value in webform.aspx when clicking a button in webform.aspx using ajax.

```
field.ascx:

    <asp:DataList ID="dtlist" runat="server" RepeatColumns="4" CellPadding="5" EnableViewState="True">
          <ItemTemplate>
    <data:Value ID="test" runat="server" />
    <ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>

Fields.ascx:
<asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" />
<asp:TextBox id="tb4"  runat="server" />


Webform.aspx
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

[WebMethod]
        public static string LoadUserControl()
        {
            using (Page page = new Page())
            {
                HtmlForm form = new HtmlForm();
                UserControl userControl = (UserControl)page.LoadControl("UserControls/field.ascx");
                form.Controls.Add(userControl);
                using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter())
                {
                    page.Controls.Add(form);
                    HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(page, writer, false);
                    return writer.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are destroying the values in the user control within the following line of your ASP.NET AJAX page method:

```
using (Page page = new Page())
```

In reality, you don't have access to the `Page` object at all within an ASP.NET AJAX page method, because it is `static` and does not at all interact with the ASP.NET Page Lifecycle.

If you are only going to have one instance of your user control, then you could use jQuery selectors in your `myFunction` JavaScript function to pull out the values for the `Label` and `TextBox` controls (be aware of the container naming that ASP.NET uses for master pages, and the control hierarchy). You can then build up an object literal to pass to the ASP.NET AJAX Page Method via the jQuery `.ajax()` function.

If you are going to have multiple instances of the user control on your page, then you will be better off using a server-side solution, coupled with the ASP.NET `UpdatePanel` control to give the illusion of asynchronous calls to the server (read: less screen flickering, because of only a partial postback). In this case, you can have `public` properties of the values you want to pull out of the user control and your server-side code will have references to each of the user control instances by ID.

So bottom line is that if you do not need to actually use a client-side JavaScript function to make a call to the server, then just use the server-side button click handler to do the logic of getting values from the server-side controls. The water quickly gets muddied when trying to get values out of server-side controls that could have multiple instances.

Comment: Can u pls illustrate an example

Comment: @Dotnet - an example of which approach, the jQuery selector grabbing the DOM element values or the server-side user control properties?